# How to browse documents from local cloud (Files) storage to share?

Tags: ios

Hi I want to get documents from "Files" app which is available on the iphone from iOS 11, for sharing purpose.I would like to show like, In whatsApp, if we want to share document it will present a view controller of Files as attached below image 1 and image 2.

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Comment: the person down voted this question, is a stupid i think. whats the wrong with the question? and before down voting  u need to give flaw where it is. useless fellow.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `UIDocumentBrowserViewController` available in `ios 11 and later`. You can see the reference here

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentbrowserviewcontroller